# Ping pong propagation in glsl compute shader possible in one call?

Tags: synchronization, glsl, memory-barriers, barrier, compute-shader

I try to implement a propagation scheme for a 32x32x32 3D texture with a glsl compute shader, it would be very nice if I could do x iterations with just one execution of the shader.

I have 3 textures, one is the source one the target and the third accumulates everything. The source and target have to be swapped for each iteration.
PseudoCode would look like
OpenGL:

```
glUseProgram(computeShaderId);
glBindImageTexture(0, srcTexId, 0, GL_TRUE, 0, GL_READ_WRITE, GL_RGBA32F);
glBindImageTexture(1, targetTexId, 0, GL_TRUE, 0, GL_READ_WRITE, GL_RGBA32F);
glBindImageTexture(2, accumulateTexId, 0, GL_TRUE, 0, GL_READ_WRITE, GL_RGBA32F);
glDispatchCompute(32,32,32);
```

GLSL:

```
#version 430
layout (local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z =1) in;
layout(rgba32f) uniform image3D srcTex;
layout(rgba32f) uniform image3D targetTex;
layout(rgba32f) uniform image3D accumulateTex;

void main() {
  ivec3 currentPos = ivec3(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xyz);

  for (int i=0;i<8;i++){
    //accumulate the values of the 6 neighbours (top,bottom,left,right,front,back)
    //by usind the current sourceTexture
    //this involes  loadImage 
    vec4 neighbourValues=getValuesFrom6Neighbours(currentPos, currentSource);

    storeImage(currentTarget,currentPos,neighbourValues);

    vec4 value=loadImage(accumTex,currentPos);
    storeImage(accumTex,currentPos,neighbourValues+value);

    //the texture are swapped, which I have a solution for so no problem here
    swapSrcAndTarget();

    //here is the Problem how to synchronize all different shader invocations?
    someKindOfBarrier();
  }
```

The thing is that I can not do all this in one workgroup beacuse of the size of the texture. Would it be in one workgroup I just could use barrier() and it would be fine.
Due to the swapping of the textures I need that all values are updated before there are read again from the next Iteration.
Has someone an idea if this is somehow possible?

Thank you
Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly as you say everything can't fit in the active threads, so I don't believe this is directly possible unless you accept there will be error (when half the values you read may be from either before or after updating). In other words, all threads must finish the first ping before moving on to pong. As only a portion of threads are physically executed at once, putting the passes in a loop won't work.

I can think of two things.

1. Breaking up the problem into tiles that can fit, but then there will be no communication between tile edges (neighbours may be stale) until finishing the kernel/dispatch.
2. Implementing your own scheduling and, using atomic opts, attempting to fetch tasks until a complete ping has been done (implying a manual sync). Only then move on to pong after a memoryBarrier(). From experience this will probably be a lot slower than putting glDispatchCompute in a for loop as you're doing.

Comment: Yes I tried to do manually sync by increment a variable with atmoic increment and tried to wait until this variable reaches the value which express that one iteration is done (32768 in this example). The problem was that I did not found a good way to pause the execution, I tried it with a while loop but that breaks the graphics driver almost instantly. 
I think you are right and the best way is to use one glDispatchCompute for one Iteration.
Thank you

Comment: I've seen a loop like this in a shader work once before: http://blog.icare3d.org/2010/07/opengl-40-abuffer-v20-linked-lists-of.html, but it doesn't take much to make GLSL fall on its face with the new stuff. For example when I tried it with a "while (!done()) no-op(); then-execute();" it used to fail but putting the code inside the loop seemed to work: "while (waiting) {if(done()) {execute(); waiting=false;}}". I've taken to looking at the shader binary (it spits out some assembly-like text along with it, at least on NVIDIA) just to make sure nothing really strange is happening. Good luck :)